# How to make element invisible in mobile size but visible in laptop size in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In tailwind css, we can say `lg:hidden` to hide element from the lg size screen.

In the below example, we do not specify the screen size so `01` is entirely hidden from any screen.

```
<div class="flex ...">
  <div class="hidden ...">01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve only show element from `lg` size but hide mobile size. However, tailwind css breakpoints are based on `min width` so if we specify `sm:hidden`, for example, min width from 768px are all hidden.

Is there any way I can just show element from specific screen size but hide below that screen size in Tailwind CSS?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<div class="flex ...">
  <div class="hidden lg:block...">01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot as I was trying hidden md:visible and then after seeing this I figured it out that by stating the element block we are inturn making it visible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 15):

Use `lg:visible` to apply the `visible` utility at only large screen sizes and above.

```
<div class="flex ...">
  <div class="invisible lg:visible">01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

Refer [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/visibility#breakpoints-and-media-queries) also

Comment: The Class 'invisible' does not shows a section on Ui but renders into the dom , so it is not preferable to use it as it may leave a gap while hiding a section . Better to use 'hidden' class

Comment: Ya you can use hidden also 

Comment: The only downside to "hidden" is there's no "unhidden" equivalent, so to devs such as myself not previously familiar with the convention of using a flex, inline, block, etc. to show an otherwise hidden component at different breakpoints, it isn't immediately clear how tf the hidden element is ever showing.

Also hypothetically couldn't hidden have an SEO impact for a crawler viewing certain breakpoints? Could be preferable to use in/visible for certain cases, though overall I think hidden is better to avoid DOM pollution.

Answer (score 14):

use hidden class as default property and then use md:flex as it will hide the div for breakpoints below md and show it on all the breakpoints above md

```
<div class="flex ...">
<div class="hidden md:flex">01</div>
<div>02</div>
<div>03</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like it's also working with `md:block` essentially changing the display property, feels like a hack though. Weird tailwind did not see this need coming..

Answer (score 11):

There is a much easier way in tailwind. Use the `max-{breakpoint}:{class}` to set the element as hidden for breakpoints below that

Ex:

```
<div class="max-sm:hidden">Hello</div>
```

This will make the above element stay hidden until the viewport increases past the width size of 640px.

Answer (score 7):

In this use case, I was trying to conditionally add a break statement to a set of words.

I used the following code:

`className="hidden lg:inline"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale-0 and scale-100 for the corresponding screen sizes, for example:

```
<div class="flex ...">
  <div class="scale-0 lg:scale-100">01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've included tailwind css, as below in file say index.html

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.15/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Have this imports, say in styles.scss

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
@import "tailwindcss/screens";
```

and then you try adding

```
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="hidden lg:block">01</div>
      <div>02</div>
      <div>03</div>
    </div>
```